# How to pass a Bluetooth Socket to another Activity using Application interface

Tags: android, ipc, handler, serializable

so from what i gather, Socket connections are neither serializable or parcelable, but i need to pass a bluetooth connection to another Activity.  i do not want to write a Service as a middle man, so please don't post this as a solution.  i've heard that there is a way to pass these types of Objects using a custom Application interface, but i cannot, for the life of me, find a working example of this.  i've seen plenty of documentation that says something to the effect of "this is possible" but nothing showing how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your app class:

```
class MyApplication extends Application{
    // your fields here
}
```

Add `name` attribute to app manifest.

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication" ../>
```

Use it in Activity:

```
MyApplication myapp = (MyApplication) getApplication();
```

Comment: after a little head scratching i got it to work.  that's twice i owe you now.  thanks.

Comment: See the following link for a detailed description on using Application class [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/how-to-declare-global-variables-in-android]